# ajax form will submit after second submit press with ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor

i have following configuration, a form submitted with ajax and a textarea using ckeditor since i use ckeditor the form will submit on second button press, on first button press form wont submit.

JS

```
 CKEDITOR.replace('_message_tokenizer', {width:"400", height:"200", toolbar : [['Styles','Font','FontSize','Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'smiley', 'Undo', 'Redo']] });





  $("#envoyer_message_tokenizer").submit(function(){

  if( $.trim($("#_message_tokenizer").val())!="" &&  $.trim($("#contacts").val())!=""){

var contacts=[];
contacts.push($("#contacts").val());

   $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
data:{"action":"envoyer_message_tokenizer", "session_id":<?php echo $session_id['id'];?>, "_message_tokenizer":$("#_message_tokenizer").val(), "_sujet":$("#_sujet").val(), "contacts":contacts} ,
  url: 'messages-ajax.php',
  success: function(data){


    $("#envoyer_message_tokenizer").fadeOut("slow", function(){
      $("#message_tokenizer").children().html(data);

    });

         }
      });
    }
 })
```

HTML

```
<form id="envoyer_message_tokenizer" method="post"  action="javascript:;">
<table cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" class="padding dotted">
<tr><td valign="top" width="130"><b class="bg">Sujet</b></td>
<td><input type="text" class="_input _input_text" style="width: 399px;" id="_sujet"/></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><b class="bg">Destinataire(s)</b> <span class="ast_oblig">*</span></td>
<td><input type="text" class="_input _input_text"  name="contacts" id="contacts"/></td></tr>
<tr><td valign="top"><b class="bg">Message</b> <span class="ast_oblig">*</span></td>
<td><textarea style="width: 399px;height: 100px;" id="_message_tokenizer"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr class="no_dotted"><td></td><td><input type="submit"  class="_submit" value="envoyer" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

i have tried ckeditor getData method but still same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent browser default submital of the form using either `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` in submit handler

```
$("#envoyer_message_tokenizer").submit(function(event) {

     /*use either method*/
     /* before code*/
    event.preventDefault();  

      /* your handler code*/

     /* OR after code*/

     return false;

})
```

Comment: still the same: form will submit on second press.

Comment: what happens if you remove `$.trim($("#_message_tokenizer").val())!="" &&` from `if` ? You can force CKEditor to update the textarea with an API method before the `if` assuming that is the issue

Comment: also need to know if AJAX is being sent or not ...  need more details about `not submitting` and how you know it is not submitting

Comment: yes it works on first submit if i remove the trim stuff, do you know why? i still need to validate those inputs.

Comment: look for CKEditor method that does the textarea update, run that before the `if`

Comment: or another approach is check the value of `getData` instead of `textarea.val()`